Not getting the desired result in the shell script
I am trying to search a particular pattern "JOB" in all the files in the mentioned directories, and the checking if the next word after JOB has at least 5 characters and if the 5th character is "H" or "I" in the next word, and then trying to print the file name, pattern and the next word in a file. but it is only printing the directory name in the output file.
#!/bin/bash
 
directories=("dir1" "dir2" "dir3" "dir4")
 
output_file="output.txt"
 
> "$output_file"
 
for dir in "${directories[@]}"; do
    echo "Searching in directory: $dir"
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        while read -r word; do
            if [[ ${#word} -ge 5 ]]; then
                fifth_char="${word:4:1}"
                if [[ $fifth_char == 'H' || $fifth_char == 'I' ]]; then
                    echo "$(basename "$file") JOB $word"
                fi
            fi
        done < <(grep -oP 'JOB \K\w+' "$file")
    done < <(find "$dir" -type f -print)
done > "$output_file"
 
echo "Search complete. Results are in $output_file."


What's the point of the separate > "$output_file" line? The file already gets wiped when the for loop starts by the redirection for that loop.

Anyhow, when you're using IFS= read -r -d '' you need to use -print0 not -print on the corresponding find.

Could you just use something like grep -o -R -P 'JOB\s+....[HI]\w*' dir[1-4]?

@Thomas, ...it's worse than a GNUism, it's an optional GNUism; even if you're 100% sure  you're using GNU grep, -P won't be there unless grep was compiled with the optional libpcre dependency enabled.

@CharlesDuffy Just edited my comment; OP is already depending on -P anyway.

@raymond, consider using set -x at the top of your script to enable trace logging, or bash -x yourscript to run it with tracing enabled as a one-off, to make it easier to identify a narrow, specific thing that's going wrong -- either that, or build a [mre] that actually creates enough of the necessary directories and files that we can copy-and-paste to run your script and see how its actual and expected behavior diverge. The -print0 bug is an obvious one, but we can't necessarily tell if there are nonobvious ones if we can't run it ourselves to test answers.

A one-liner solution with GNU grep might be: grep -oER 'JOB[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]{4}[HI][^[:blank:]]*' "${directories[@]}"

personal opinion; if you're going to use grep -P, you might as well just use perl.

These days, perl may no longer be faster than grep, but it is almost certainly better than grep | while read.

Depends. If you run into one of the nasty corner cases where PCREs go into polynomial time, then either perl or grep -P will be vastly slower than traditional grep.

@M.NejatAydin If you use GNU grep you can simplify a bit with grep -oER 'JOB\s+\w{4}[HI]\w*' "${directories[@]}".

Define the meaning of "next word after JOB". For instance, if you have a line foo JOB   bar-baz.boom, what would be the "next word after JOB"? And if you have a line fooJOBbar baz, what would then be the next word?

Something like this.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

directories=("dir1" "dir2" "dir3" "dir4")
regex='JOB[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]{4}[HI][^[:blank:]]*)[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]*)'

while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
  printf 'Searching for directory %s\n' "${dir}"
  while IFS= read -ru"$fd" file; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ $regex ]]; then
      printf 'filename: <%s>\npattern: <%s>\nnext_word: <%s>\n' "$(basename "$dir")" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
  done {fd}< "$dir"
done < <(find "${directories[@]}" -type f -print0) > output.txt 2>&1



One should loop through the output of find and not embed it in a loop. If there are 1k directories then find will be executed 1k times as well.


This might be all you need, using find plus GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), \</\> word boundaries, and \s/\w shorthand:
dirs=("dir1" "dir2" "dir3" "dir4")
find "${dirs[@]}" -type f -exec awk '
    match($0,/\<JOB\>\s+(\w{5,})/,a) && (substr(a[1],5,1) ~ /[HI]/) {
        print FILENAME, "JOB", a[1]
    }
' {} +

assuming your JOBS word only appears once per input line.
The above is obviously just an untested guess since no sample input/output was provided in the question.

If you have ack installed and you are OK with printing the file path (e.g., dir1/foo) instead of the base name (foo), you can try:
ack 'JOB\s+(\w{4}[HI]\w*)' -h --output '$f JOB $1' "${directories[@]}" > "$output_file"


No need to write a script for something like that.
Try to find a regular expression, describing your needs (find the word "JOB", and after that, have four characters and after that, an 'i' or an 'h'), you get a grep command like this:
grep "JOB.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][IHih]" file1.txt


The dot after "JOB" stands for any character (space, newline, ...)
[a-zA-Z0-9] means any letter or digit. In case your words might contain more characters, please add them.
[IHih] means 'i' or 'h'.

Let's see what this does to this file:
JOB 1234 1234
JOB 12345 12345
Nothing
123456 JOB 123456
1234567 JOB IIIIIIIIII
1234567 JOB hahahahaha

Result:
1234567 JOB IIIIIIIIII
1234567 JOB hahahahaha

Now, in order to turn a grep into a directory search, you might opt for grep -r, or combine grep with find, something like:
find ./ -name "*.txt" 
     -exec grep "JOB.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][IHih]" {} /dev/null \;

(the presence of /dev/null in this command is a dirty trick to ensure the output of the filename itself.)
It seems you can use find on different directories, turning your command into something like:
find $dir1 $dir2 $dir3 $dir4 -name "*.txt" 
     -exec grep "JOB.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][IHih]" {} /dev/null \;

Obviously this won't be perfect, you here you have a good start.
... and also obviously, you can simplify your regular expression, dropping the small letters and capitals ([a-z instead of [a-zA-z), but in order to do so, you need to use grep -i, which will automatically also find JoB (where you might have small letters).
